# Set environment variable in shell script/access in Java program

Tags: java, linux, shell, ubuntu-10.04

I want to set environment using shell scrip in Ubuntu 10.04 and want to access in java program. I have wrote shell script like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
export JAVA=/home/ubuntu
echo "Variable $JAVA"
```

and my java program is :

```
import java.util.Map;

public class SystemEnv
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Map<String, String> variables = System.getenv();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet())
        {
           String name = entry.getKey();
           String value = entry.getValue();
           System.out.println(name + "=" + value);
        }
        System.out.println(System.getenv(("JAVA")));
    }
}
```

When I execute this command without shell script it works well, but in shell script it does not.

Comment: Please show the shell script in its entirety (i.e. including the `java` command you use to run your code). Also, when you say it doesn't work, what exactly are the symptoms?

Comment: Please check output from env command , before launching the java program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you sourcing the script?

```
$./myscript.sh
```

or

```
$source ./myscript.sh
```

The second will set the environment variable to current shell. The java program looks ok.

EDIT: based on the comment

It was a problem related to subshell.  A quick read is
[What is the difference between executing a bash script and sourcing a bash script?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)

Comment: Thanks Jayan, I have tried with second command and it works as charm...thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do exactly?

Running `JAVA=/home/ubuntu java SystemEnv` works fine (i.e. it outputs "/home/ubuntu")

If you want to export environment variables to the parent process, you have to source it:

```
source ./myscript.sh
. ./myscript.sh # Alternative form
```

Comment: Pedantically, in bash, `source` is the alternative form.

Comment: How to make it Global? i.e. i can access from tomcat as well.

Comment: @AnandSoni I don't think it can be done once Tomcat (or any other program) has started (someone please correct me if I'm wrong). I think you're on Ubuntu, take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

Comment: @lum. Thanks for replay but have done with writing that export statements in /etc/init.d/tomcat6 at top and restarted the tomcat server by /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart. So, now it that env. variable will be accessed by web app.