# Run environment for ubuntu service

Tags: ubuntu

According to Ubuntu documentation when running `sudo service service_name start`,
the environment from `/etc/environment` is not referenced.
Service runs a System V init script in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /. 
I want the environment to be exported without a user context.
How can it be done?