# Set environment variable in shell script and access in Java program

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix, processbuilder

This question is a followup on [Set environment variable in shell script/access in Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140182/set-environment-variable-in-shell-script-access-in-java-program). I am trying to fetch the environment variable in Java after running a shell script but unable to do so

Shell Script: getDetails.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: getDetails.sh
export userDetails="USER123"
# echo "User Details for App :$userDetails"
```

Java method:

```
String details = new String("source " + "getDetails.sh");
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", details);
Process getPwdProc = processBuilder.start();
System.out.println("Details - " + processBuilder.environment().get("userDetails"));
```

The java method returns/prints null for the environment variable - userDetails.

P.S. - Please note that the use of InputStream/BufferedReader to read the userDetails is not possible here as echoing the details is not allowed for the program/organization.

Answer (score 5):

Exporting an environment variable from a `bash` process does not make it "global", it means that it is inherited (copied) to child processes.  That is, processes run by the `bash` process which exported it.

Here Java is the *parent*, and there is no (legal) way to inject a variable into a parent process from a child. The variable has to be set and exported before the Java is run.

I suggest a "wrapper" bash script that first exports the variable and then runs your Java application.

Comment: Thanks @cdarke, your comment is indeed helpful. I exported the variable from parent bash that was calling java: such that export script is now the parent and java is the child process. With this change, I have the environment variable available in java code.